# Can't pass more than 2 things in Socket.emit

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket.io v4.5.1 and tried running this code from the client side:

```
createButtonSecond.addEventListener("click", createButtonSecondClick);
function createButtonSecondClick() {
  hide(createRoomSecond)
  unhide(shareCode);

  setRoom(code);
  setCross(symbol.value);
  setFirstPlayer(firstPlayer.value);
  const obj = {}
  obj.room = room;
  obj.cross = cross;
  obj.firstPlayer = firstPlayer;
  socket.emit("create-room", obj);  // this is where the problem occurs
}
```

My goal was to pass all three info to the server. But whenever I try passing more than 2 info, I get **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.** This also happens when I try doing something like

```
socket.emit("create-room", room, cross, firstPlayer);
```

but it doesn't happen when I try

```
socket.emit("create-room", room, cross);
```

I even tried doing

```
socket.emit("create-room", room);
socket.emit("create-room-cross", cross);
socket.emit("create-room-firstPlayer", firstPlayer);
```

but still the issue persists. I searched socket docs but couldn't find anything. What might be the issue?

Comment: Is there a stack trace?

Comment: What is firstPlayer? Does it have a reference to itself, by chance?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with passing 3 things, and everything to do with passing firstPlayer.

Comment: Some function is being called infinitely. Look at your code and try to find that function.

Comment: Yeah sorry I was dumb. Apparently firstPlayer was the name of both an html element and something I defined with useState. Thanks for the help : D